# how does realization of random variable work?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, inference

Reading different resources about statistical inference, I have hard to time to build good intuition about how some fundamental tasks stated. Many resources say something like this:

1. Given random sample $X = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$, where $X_i$ are iid with some distribution function $F$, (or pdf $f$)            (condition *)
2. $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ - are realization, of $X_1, \dots, X_n$            (condition **)

The task is to estimate $F$ or $f$ (Whether it is parametric or non-parametric estimation)

I fully understand (*) and it is mathematically well defined to me. My both questions relate to better understanding (**)

Two questions:

1) what does it actually mean “realization of random variable”? Or what does it mean “run experiment and obtain value $x_i$ from $X_i$.) I find those statements lack mathematical rigor and just don’t see any additional links for more read.

2) if there is some procedure “realization of random variable” defined, why different $X_i$ random variables needed to set the theory? Wouldn’t it be more straightforward to consider a single random variable $X$, consider $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ - independent realizations of $X$. The task would be still the same - estimate distribution of $X$.

Comment: Since you fully understand $(*)$ and ask for mathematical rigor, please observe that  by definition $X:\mathbb\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ while $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=X(\omega)$ for some particular $\omega\in\Omega.$ Note how this simply and automatically handles question (2), too.

Comment: @whuber, it makes more sense now. Thus, "realize random variable", or "run experiment" means "take value $X(\omega)$ given $\omega$". Are there any assumptions made about $\omega \in \Omega$ that generates the $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$

Comment: Yes: $\omega$ is governed by a probability on $\Omega.$ I like to use Freedman *et al.'s* "tickets in a box" model: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A919+tickets%2Brandom%2Bvariable.  In that terminology, $\omega$ is the ticket you draw from the box.  It's a metaphor for your experimental observations.  $X$ provides a set of numbers to describe the results.  The entire box represents $\Omega;$ the numbers written on the tickets $\omega$ describe $X;$ the particular set of numbers you are seeing--$X(\omega)$--are the realization of your experiment.

Comment: Note that the mathematical definition of a random variable does not require a probability: it only requires a specified algebra of subsets of $\Omega.$  In statistics we entertain the possibility that this algebra may have various probability functions.  From the realization we attempt to estimate which one it might be.  Thus, a given random variable $X$ may be governed by different distributions, depending on what the probability function is.

Comment: @whuber, the link doesn't work, could you please double check. I'll absorb and reply later, thanks!

Comment: It still works for me, but maybe that's because of how the search string is formed: I'll modify it.  If you still can't access it, just search our site for keywords "tickets+random+variable+user:919".

Comment: link fixed, thanks.
@whuber do I understand correctly that in the "tickets in a box" metaphor, there can be multiple tickets sharing the same $\omega$ (because as you said $\omega$ is driven by probability, however from the suggested links it is clear that tickets are drawn "blindly", all tickets have "equal" chance to be drawn)